# A-frame / Three js streaming memory leak

Tags: three.js, aframe

I am trying to live stream 360 video via A-frame, by setting the src attribute of the sky to a Flask endpoint that serves each frame when a GET request is made. The code works, however, even though I have disabled caching, the memory usage of the page consistently increases over time and it slows down significantly. Much of the memory seems to go to what's labeled as (closure) in the chrome dev tools (32 bytes per frame).

[Chrome memory usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGVnO.png)

[image]

Code:

```
<a-sky set-sky=""></a-sky>


THREE.Cache.enabled = false


 AFRAME.registerComponent('set-sky', {
   schema: {default:''},
   init: function() {
     this.timeout = setInterval(this.updateSky.bind(this), 41);
     this.sky = this.el;
     this.sky.setAttribute( 'crossorigin', "Anonymous");
     this.sky.setAttribute( 'src', "http://0.0.0.0:5000/video_feed?" + new Date().getTime());

   },
   remove: function() {
     clearInterval(this.timeout);
     this.el.removeObject3D(this.object3D);
   },
   updateSky: function() {
       THREE.texture = {}
       this.sky.setAttribute( 'src', "http://0.0.0.0:5000/video_feed?" + new Date().getTime());
   }
 });
```

On the server side I also configured the request not to store the images

```
response.headers['Pragma-Directive'] = 'no-cache'
response.headers['Cache-Directive'] = 'no-cache'
response.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'no-store   '
response.headers['Pragma'] = 'no-cache'
response.headers['Expires'] = '0'
```

What can I do to prevent data from being stored in memory?

Comment: Maybe it's your use of [bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) which "creates a new function".. every 41 milliseconds

Comment: also, avoid "new Date()", call Date,now

Comment: @2pha I got rid of the unnecessary .bind(), but the problem remains.

Comment: Try expanding the (closure) line in devtools to see what other information it provides.